# Configure Modem for Bittorrent downloads

Tags: download, speed, bittorrent, modem

How can I configure the Modem to get maximum download speed for Bit torrents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure port forwarding , depending on the modem/ router the steps will vary. Find our what port your client is listening on then visit [http://portforward.com](http://portforward.com/)/ for steps to configure the modem / router

Comment: Very useful link

Answer (score 2):

If you talking about dial up modems then, there is no special configuration that will help you achieve greater speeds. Your p2p speed will depend on overall connection speed of modem 40kbps, 52.6kbps, 128kbps and so on. Also speed will depend on peers who are seeding files to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sysadmin related, but what the hey:

What a huge can of worms.

Many torrent clients (like Azureus) support UPnP so if your router also supports UPnP (and it is enabled), then the client can take care of it for you.

Other than that, you need to find out what port your software uses (it's usually a high port, like 16000 or something) and forward that port in your router to the downloading machine. Most software will allow you to choose your own port, so it shouldn't be too hard to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure that this question is in much relation to Sys Admin stuff)

Have you tried [Google yet?](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=configure+modem+for+bit+torrent&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)

[How to configure your router for bittorrent](http://p2p.weblogsinc.com/2005/04/24/how-to-configure-your-router-to-allow-fast-bittorrent-downloads/)

and you should also [configure your client correctly](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/bittorrent/qt/bittorrentports.htm).