# port forwarding?

Tags: download, bittorrent, port-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure Modem for Bittorrent downloads](https://superuser.com/questions/5246/configure-modem-for-bittorrent-downloads)

any guides on portforwarding? I want to speed up my torrent downloads

Comment: What OS? There's probably a dupe for it.

Comment: this one: http://superuser.com/questions/5246/configure-modem-for-bittorrent-downloads ?

Comment: @Nrew, after 50 questions in 23 days, I'd expect you know how to search this site...? Please read the FAQs, thanks!

Comment: Ha! "There's an app for that" replaced by "There's a dupe for that" :P

Comment: @Nrew - As you don't respond to e-mail, please be aware that your account has been suspended for 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://portforward.com/