# Redirect ip-address to localhost

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, web-hosting

I am trying to learn to host website on home pc. For this I have installed apache tomcat.

I have also done port forwarding in my modem. I checked it with http://www.canyouseeme.org/.

When I am writing `localhost` in the address bar of chrome I am getting the page showing "If you are seeing this page means you apache is running" .

But the problem is that when I enter 117.xxx.xxx.xxx (my ip) then it opens the modem's home page(login).

I want that I can give my ip-address to my friend so that he can see the website hosted at my computer. But when he goes to http://117.xxx.xxx.xxx he gets the error `page not found`. What should I do so that my friend can see the website hosted at my computer. Please help.

Comment: Port forwarding is the answer.  However, this will be a duplicate.  There are a *lot* of answers on the website for port forwarding.  Trying to find the most applicable one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [port forwarding?](http://superuser.com/questions/87803/port-forwarding) 
Look at the accepted answer

Comment: @Keltari I have done port forwarding and checked it with http://www.canyouseeme.org/. The site is saying "Success: I can see your service on 117.xxx.xxx.xxx on port (80) Your ISP is not blocking port 80". But still I am redirected to Modem's login page when I enter 117.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: @AjaySainy: You _will_ get redirected to the modem from within the LAN. Port forwarding concerns external calls. If the port forwarding is working, and your web server is set up, then your friend should be able to contact it. View your web server logs and see why it doesn't work when your friend tries to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason why you are using Apache Tomcat to host a website? Tomcat is an web application server which requires in depth knowledge to correctly configure. In your case, you need to configure Tomcat to listen to your IP in your `server.xml` file and restart Tomcat.

If you are not planning to write Java Servlet or JSP pages, and would just be doing HTML/PHP, then you should use really use Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/).